# Why does it still say 0 although I am adding on to it?

Tags: python

#### READ THIS FIRST BEFORE

- Firstly, allow me to explain what you should input to get the mistake.

  - Run the program.
  - Name your company to anything.
  - Then see company stats by clicking 1.
  - After that work on your company by clicking 2
  - Then hire people by clicking 1
  - Hire maybe two or three people by clicking the respective numbers.
  - Then click 6 and go back.
  - Then see the company stats again.

  - **PROBLEM HERE**. The number of employees remain the same

### WHY?

### What I think I did ?

- My problem is in the function `employees()` on line 24.

- Although I do `employee_num += 1`, the number of employees remain the same.

This is my question. Please tell me how to fix that and also provide a reason.

CODE:

```
from colored import fg
import random

# Colors
green = fg("green")
white = fg("white")
yellow = fg("yellow")
blue = fg("blue")
magenta = fg("magenta")
red = fg('red')
wheat_4 = fg("wheat_4")

# Main Assets
nums_3 = ['1', '2', '3']
nums_6 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
revenue = 0
products = 0
employee_num = 0

# Start with company's name
company_name = input(red + "What would you like to name your company: ")

def company():
    def employees():
        employee_num = 0
        # getting file data
        employees_open = open('employees.txt', 'r')
        employees_open_read = employees_open.readlines()
        employees_open_read_fixed = [line.strip() for line in employees_open_read]
        employees_open = employees_open.close()

        #Employee names
        random_employee1 = random.choice(employees_open_read_fixed)
        random_employee2 = random.choice(employees_open_read_fixed) 
        random_employee3 = random.choice(employees_open_read_fixed) 

        # Salaries
        salaries = [10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000]
        employee_salary1 = random.choice(salaries)
        employee_salary2 = random.choice(salaries)
        employee_salary3 = random.choice(salaries)

        #Names in a list
        salary_payed = 0

        while True:
            hiring = input(f"{yellow}\nHere is a list of people you can hire:\n\n         [1] Name: {random_employee1} | Salary: ${employee_salary1}\n         [2] Name: {random_employee2} | Salary: ${employee_salary2}\n         [3] Name: {random_employee3} | Salary: ${employee_salary3}\n         [4] Or go back to main page. \n\nEnter the number of the person you would like to hire: ---> ")
            while hiring in nums_3:
                if hiring == '1':
                    salary_payed += employee_salary1
                    random_employee1 = random.choice(employees_open_read_fixed)
                    employee_num += 1
                    break

                if hiring == '2':
                    salary_payed += employee_salary2
                    random_employee2 = random.choice(employees_open_read_fixed)
                    employee_num += 1
                    break

                if hiring == '3':
                    salary_payed += employee_salary3
                    random_employee3 = random.choice(employees_open_read_fixed)
                    employee_num += 1
                    break


            if hiring == '4':
                break



    while True:
        first_choice = input(magenta + "\nWhat do you want to do:\n\n         [1] See your company's stats\n         [2] Work on your company.\n---> ")

        while first_choice in nums_3:
            if first_choice == '1':
                print(f"{company_name.title()}:\n{green}Revenue: {revenue}\nEmployees: {employee_num}\nProducts Sold: {products}")
                break

            if first_choice == '2':
                company_work = input(wheat_4 + "Here is what you can do with your company:\n\n         [1] Hire new people\n         [2] Build a phone.\n         [3]Buy Shares\n         [4]Sell shares\n         [5]Sell your products\n         [6] Or go back.\n---> ")

                if company_work == '6':
                    break

                while company_work in nums_3:
                    if company_work == '1':
                        employees()
                        break

                


company()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify a variable in a function other than the place that variable exists, you need either a [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) or [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) statement, depending on whether your variable is global or not. Your `employee_num` is global, so you should put

```
global employee_num
```

as the first line of any function which will modify it.